# Typescript not asserting types when class implements interface

Tags: typescript

```
interface IInterface2<T, C> {
    propA: T,
    propB: C
}

interface IInterface {
    doSomething(test: IInterface2<{a: number, c: string}, {b: number}>): void
}

class Test implements IInterface {
    doSomething(test: IInterface2<{ a: number },{ b: number }>): void {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.")
    } 
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJKvNeSBMAeAFQBpkBhAPmQG8AoZe5ABygHtGBBALmWLoebYAhbqRoBfGjVCRYiFOkyyk1PvQAmLAMosAthDAALUAHMAFJADOYbgpnYI+KnG4gArjoBG0Egm5WoJmIkVB4u7l5QYuQAlNwAbizAauKSCAA2cBYWPBBWyMA6jGkQeuDZtlhyKgzIGtp6hibmudZoGHZyjsjOyG6e0MhBVMihveEDUbHICUnVNQyGrADuvRArAKJQrFCmAEQAsvoGLGq9LGD5hcWlkGoAdLvRqoPI4kA)

The class should gave an error telling that the "c" property is missing, but doesn't give.

Comment: There's no error because it's perfectly type safe.  `Test`'s `doSomething()` accepts every argument that `IInterface`'s `doSomething()` method accepts.  Even if it weren't type safe, TypeScript's methods are compared *bivariantly* and there would be no error.  Can you demonstrate with code what problems come up here for you, assuming there are such problems?

Comment: I see, thanks. The problem is that I'm generating interfaces with methods based on openAPI and than I implement these interfaces. My goal is if someone changes some prop in any method, I need to change the implementation of these methods, and since every member of the team can change the openAPI file, is harder to follow every change without typescript telling me.

Comment: Why would you *need* to change the implementation if the original implementation is type safe? Could you demonstrate with code examples the kind of problem you'd run into?

Comment: @jcalz Sure, I have this code, generated automatically from one openAPI generator lib, and my implementation [pastbin code](https://pastebin.com/L2ebaKTT). If, for some reason, the method `deleteOrganizationAddress(req: Request<{ organizationPk: number; addressPk: number;  someOtherProp: number}, ...)` has changed by adding `someOtherProp: number`, the class with this `implements` will not know this change.

Comment: Sorry, I need a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  If there are external dependencies unavailable to me, then I can't demonstrate the issue.  Toy examples are fine, they just need to show why it matters.

Comment: @jcalz thank you for your time, here is the full example: [github example repo](https://github.com/ruiaraujolink/stackoverflow-typescript-example). I have written some notes on the readme

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to be installing a repo to answer a SO question.  Please review the guidelines for what constitutes a [mre].  Maybe we're having a communication barrier?  I'm looking for a small example that demonstrates something going wrong when a property is added to one of the interface's method's arguments, so I can see the problem and possibly propose a different way to write it that would give a compiler warning in that situation.